# Get IP addresses of all k8s pods from within a container

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service called `my-service` with an endpoint called `refreshCache`. `my-service` is hosted on multiple servers, and occasionally I want an event in `my-service` on one of the servers to trigger `refreshCache` on `my-service` on all servers. To do this I manually maintain a list of all the servers that host `my-service`, pull that list, and send a REST request to `<server>/.../refreshCache` for each server.

I'm now migrating my service to k8s. Similarly to before, where I was running `refreshCache` on all servers that hosted `my-service`, I now want to be able to run `refreshCache` on all the pods that host `my-service`. Unfortunately I cannot manually maintain a list of pod IPs, as my understanding is that IPs are ephemeral in k8s, so I need to be able to dynamically get the IPs of all pods in a node, from within a container in one of those pods. Is this possible?

Note: I'm aware this information is available with `kubectl get endpoints ...`, however `kubectl` will not be available within my container.

Comment: Sounds like something a bash script might be good for

Comment: You can use the k8s client of your language, or simply call the REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `kubectl` to access the Kubernetes API. You can do it with any tool that can make HTTP requests.

The Kubernetes API is a simple HTTP REST API, and all the authentication information that you need is present in the container if it runs as a Pod in the cluster.

To [get the Endpoints object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#read-endpoints-v1-core) named `my-service` from within a container in the cluster, you can do:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
  https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/endpoints/my-service
```

*Note: replace `{namespace}` with the namespace of the `my-service` Endpoints resource.*

And to extract the IP addresses of the returned JSON, you could pipe the output to a tool like `jq`:

```
... | jq -r '.subsets[].addresses[].ip'
```

**Note that the Pod from which you are executing this needs read permissions for the Endpoints resource, otherwise the API request is denied.**

You can do this with a ClusterRole, ClusterRoleBinding, and Service Account (you need to set this up only once):

```
kubectl create sa endpoint-reader
kubectl create clusterrole endpoint-reader --verb=get,list --resource=endpoints
kubectl create clusterrolebinding endpoint-reader --serviceaccount=default:endpoint-reader --clusterrole=endpoint-reader
```

Then, use the `endpoint-reader` ServiceAccount for the Pod from which you want to execute the above `curl` command by specifying it in the [`pod.spec.serviceAccountName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#podspec-v1-core) field.

Granting permissions for any other API operations (i.e. combinations of verbs and resources) works in the same way.

Comment: Just curious, is there any good reason to not, say, just bind the `endpoint-reader` `ClusterRole` to the `default` `ServiceAccount` for that namespace? (assuming for this example all pods in that namespace should have access to the `endpoints` resource)

Comment: You can do that, if you're sure that there are only pods that need the `endpoint-reader` ClusterRole in this namespace. But it's generally a good practice to use dedicated ServiceAccounts and not assign any permissions to the default ServiceAccount of a namespace. This way you can prevent that pods accidentally get permissions that they don't need if someday nevertheless you decide to add some other pods to this namespace.

Answer (score 4):

For achieving this the best way would be to use a K8s config inside the pod.

For this the K8s Client can help. Here is an example python script that can be used to get pods and their metadata from inside the pod.

```py
from kubernetes import client, config


def trigger_refresh_cache():
    # it works only if this script is run by K8s as a POD
    config.load_incluster_config()

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(label_selector='app=my-service')
    for i in ret.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
              (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
        # Rest of the logic goes here to trigger endpoint
```

Here the method `load_incluster_config()` is used which loads the kubeconfig inside pod via the service account attached to that pod.

Comment: That's cool! Didn't know that existed. I only ended up marking the other answer correct though because it seems more widely applicable