# Kubernetes API timeout on listNamespacedPod

Tags: kubernetes

Using some simple code examples, I am trying to list all the pods in my namespace and find their IPs e.g.

```
ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
// now you are safe to construct a CoreV1Api.
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
V1PodList list =
    api.listNamespacedPod("myNS", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 30, false);
for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
  System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
}
```

Result:

> SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Guessing it's something to do with the config maybe. I've also tried `Config.fromCluster()` but got the same result.

I should mention that this code is running in a pod in that namespace

Comment: You can list the pods in name space by using this command `kubectl get pod -n <name_space_name>`. Refer to this [doc](https://www.studytonight.com/post/how-to-list-all-resources-in-a-kubernetes-namespace) by iamabhishek for more information to list all the resources in the namespace.

Comment: Compare your API with the code available in this [doc](https://www.baeldung.com/java-kubernetes-namespaces-selectors#using_namespaces), might help you in resolving this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am familiar with the kubectl tools, but I need to find the IPs inside a rest service, so that I can call the same endpoint on all the other pods. I tried that Baeldung code verbatim and got the same time out result unfortunately.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/) ,  You can get the list of Pod IP addresses using 

`kubectl get pods -l app=hostnames 

-o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.status.podIP}}{{"\\n"}}{{end}}'` . You can also refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913132/)

Comment: Again, thanks I am familiar with kubectl, but this is not going to help me discover the pod IPs within a running Spring Boot app

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an egress rule from my app to the kube api server

Comment: If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community. One line answer is not a perfect way .